# Http Request headers not always available in AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, http-headers, serverless-framework, api-gateway

I use API Gateway and AWS Lambda through the serverless framework for creating API endpoints. The lambda function get deployed as lambda proxies by default.

When I send a `POST` request to one of my endpoints, I include custom headers like `client_version: 1.0.0`.

Now the weird thing occurs that the Lambda function not always get the header `client_version` when making requests to an endpoint. This mainly occurs a few minutes after deploying the service to aws, after some time the lambda function receives the header. But sometimes it receives the header and then some time in the future it doesn't receive the header again.

I tested making requests to a single endpoint from my machine and from online services, and it seems like that it is fully independent.

Meaning that the weird error can occur from my machine `POST` request while the online service `POST` request successfully manage to pass the header to the lambda function, or other way round or both at the same time.

This drives me crazy as I literally have no clue what the problem might be and I need to send custom headers consistently to my endpoints. Any help appreciated.

**Serverless config**

serverless.yml:

```
custom: ${file(serverless_config/custom.yml):custom}
functions: ${file(serverless_config/functions.yml):functions}
resources: ${file(serverless_config/resources.yml):resources}

service: "${self:custom.WEBSERVICE_NAME}"

provider:
    name: aws
    profile: "${self:custom.CURRENT_PROFILE}"
    stage: "${self:custom.CURRENT_DEPLOY_MODE}"
    region: "${self:custom.AWS_DEPLOY_REGION}"
    runtime: "${self:custom.AWS_LAMBDA_RUNTIME}"
    memorySize: ${self:custom.AWS_LAMBDA_MEMORY_SIZE}
    timeout: "${self:custom.AWS_LAMBDA_TIMEOUT}"
    logRetentionInDays: ${self:custom.AWS_CLOUDWATCH_LOG_TTL}
    environment: ${file(serverless_config/environment.yml):environment}
```

functions.yml

```
functions:
    Account-Create:
        role: DefaultLambdaIAMRole
        handler: src/v1/Account/Create/Email/main.main
        events:
            - http:
                path: v${self:custom.CURRENT_API_VERSION}/account/create-email
                method: POST
```

custom.yml:

```
custom:

    WEBSERVICE_NAME: account-service
    WEBSERVICE_ENDPOINT: "api.accountservice.testing.galaxgate.com"

    DEFAULT_DEPLOY_MODE: dev
    stage: "${opt:stage, self:custom.DEFAULT_DEPLOY_MODE}"
    CURRENT_DEPLOY_MODE: "${self:custom.stage}"
    CURRENT_PROFILE: galaxfinity
    CURRENT_API_VERSION: "1"

    WEBSERVICE_PREFIX: "${self:custom.WEBSERVICE_NAME}-${self:custom.CURRENT_DEPLOY_MODE}-"


    AWS_ACCOUNT_ID: "XXXXXXXXX"
    AWS_DEPLOY_REGION: eu-central-1 # dep: _config.js
    AWS_LAMBDA_RUNTIME: nodejs12.x
    AWS_LAMBDA_TIMEOUT: 30
    AWS_LAMBDA_MEMORY_SIZE: 512

    IAM_LAMBDA_POLICY_NAME: "${self:custom.WEBSERVICE_PREFIX}policy-lambda"
    IAM_LAMBDA_ROLE_NAME: "${self:custom.WEBSERVICE_PREFIX}role-lambda"

    AWS_CLOUDWATCH_LOG_TTL: 180 # in days


    DB_TABLE_DELETION_POLICY_VALUES:
        dev: Delete
        prod: Retain
    DB_TABLE_DELETION_POLICY: ${self:custom.DB_TABLE_DELETION_POLICY_VALUES.${self:custom.stage}}

    S3_BUCKET_DELETION_POLICY_VALUES:
        dev: Delete
        prod: Retain
    S3_BUCKET_DELETION_POLICY: ${self:custom.S3_BUCKET_DELETION_POLICY_VALUES.${self:custom.stage}}

    customDomain:
        endpointType: 'regional'
        securityPolicy: tls_1_2
        domainName: '${self:custom.WEBSERVICE_ENDPOINT}'
        certificateName: '${self:custom.WEBSERVICE_ENDPOINT}'
        basePath: '${self:custom.CURRENT_DEPLOY_MODE}'
        stage: ${self:custom.CURRENT_DEPLOY_MODE}
        createRoute53Record: true
```

**Some images**

Same request result into different outcomes.

[Postman headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGfF3.png)

[Sometimes without header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezhyR.png)

[Most of the time with header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Htts3.png)

**UPDATE 1**
I was able to get logs directly from the API Gateway input. Seems like API Gateway isn't even receiving the custom headers. Still can't believe that Postman might causes the trouble.

```
Method request headers: {Accept=*/*, Cache-Control=no-cache, User-Agent=PostmanRuntime/7.24.1, X-Forwarded-Proto=https, X-Forwarded-For=5.147.136.132, Host=api.accountservice.testing.galaxgate.com, Postman-Token=9236b95a-3cef-4e04-a188-38e996122811, Accept-Encoding=gzip, deflate, br, X-Forwarded-Port=443, X-Amzn-Trace-Id=Root=1-5ec30f6a-6e719a6a7cc4e1c12e54c030, Content-Type=text/plain}
```

**UPDATE 2**

Here you can see the weirdness of that all. I use reqbin.com to send two requests, one from US server and one from DE server. The server should respond with `PAYLOAD_INVALID`. But when no header field `client_version` is set it is responding with `CLIENT_VERSION_MISSING`.

Since when do header fields mystically disappear while being sent over the internet?

[image: US server request]

[image: DE request]

**BIG FINAL UPDATE**

I found the solution: It turns out that changing the custom header `client_version` to `X-Client-Version` solves the issue and the header is received consistently. I don't know why something like this can affect the functionality of API Gateway but im fine with the working solution.

Comment: Can you reproduce the error locally like using Postman?

Comment: Yeah I use Postman to make the requests and its like that when i deploy the service to aws theres like a 33% chance that the "bug" starts. Then its usually like the first 10-30 requests I do with Postman end up in not delivering the client_version header to the lambda functiona and after some time it works (even tho I dont change anything)

Comment: And then again after some more time the lambda function might again start not receiving the custom headers (without any changes made to the service)

Comment: Can you post your sererless config?

Answer (score 1):

you need to set your custom headers on the cors
https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway#enabling-cors

for example:

```
functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
    events:
      - http:
          path: hello
          method: get
          cors:
            origin: '*'
            headers:
              - Content-Type
              - X-Amz-Date
              - Authorization
              - client_version
            allowCredentials: false
```

Comment: I did that as well with no luck. But i found the solution: It turns out that changing the custom header `client_version` to `X-Client-Version` solves the issue and the header is received consistently. I don't know why something like this can affect the functionality of API Gateway but im fine with the working solution.

Comment: @iOSonntag, same issue, used header like mobile_version, changed to X-Mobile-Version, and boom ... it's work)) thanks for solution